# azure search inbuilt cognitive skill not extracting the valid location name

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

While using the inbuilt cognitive skill in azure search,[image] extracting some wrong entity-location.

Comment: are you extracting this from image files? have you checked the metadata and looked for those values?

Comment: Did you try changing the `minimumPrecision` parameter for the entity recognition skill? This can significantly help remove false positives.